# Strange behaviour with horizontalArrangement using JetPack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I don't understand why my switches are not aligned, why it is expanding outside the screenview ? of course I didn't succeed so far to find a proper solution to align my switches with jetpack compose.

[image: preview from Android Studio]

the kotlin code :

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Switch
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

class ToolsActivityK2 : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                ToolContent_()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun Preview_ToolContent_() {
    ToolContent_()
}

@Composable
fun SettingsSwitch_(
    subtitle: String
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Text(
            subtitle,
            Modifier.padding(end = 16.dp)
        )
        Switch(checked = false, onCheckedChange = null)
    }
}

@Composable
fun ToolContent_() {
    Column {
        SettingsSwitch_("launch something 1")
        SettingsSwitch_("launch launch launch launch again and again and again something 2")
        SettingsSwitch_("launch something 3")
    }
}
```

if I replace the switches by images, it's worse the image for line 2 does not show on screen ! I for sure miss something but I cannot figure what

Configuration infos:

Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.1.0-rc02'
androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `weight` to achieve something like this,

[image]

**Complete code**

```
@Composable
fun SettingsSwitch_(
    subtitle: String
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    ) {
        Text(
            subtitle,
            Modifier.padding(end = 16.dp).weight(1f)
        )
        Switch(checked = false, onCheckedChange = null)
    }
}
```

### Reason

I have applied background color to all the components in your code to show how they are placed.

```
@Composable
fun SettingsSwitch_(
    subtitle: String
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Red)
            .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
    ) {
        Text(
            subtitle,
            Modifier.background(Cyan).padding(end = 16.dp)// .weight(1f)
        )
        Switch(checked = false, onCheckedChange = null, modifier = Modifier.background(Green))
    }
}
```

And this code gives the following layout.

[image: Screenshot]

So, you can see that the `Text` has occupied the full space available in the `Row`. Hence the `Switch` appears in the wrong position.

### More info

If we look into the docs for `Arrangement.SpaceBetween` we can see,

> Place children such that they are spaced evenly across the main axis,
> without free space before the first child or after the last child.
> Visually: 1##2##3 for LTR or 3##2##1 for RTL.

All the `Arrangement` options only affect the extra free space between the children. Since the is no extra free space in the second `Row` the `Arrangement` does not have any effect there.